# Creating a base multisig with the same address as an eth multisig

Tags: gnosis-safe, multisignature

Is it possible to create a safe multisig on base that has the same address as a safe multisig deployed on eth mainnet?

During a token presale we had a few customers accidentally send their funds to a our safe address on base instead of mainnet and we are trying to determine if the funds are recoverable at all or totally lost.

Any guidance is hugely appreciated!

Comment: It may or may not be possible, depending on which contracts were used for eth multisig and if they're deployed to the same address on the base network

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible, if the address is not already taken by someone else . Go to Base's SafeProxyFactory address and use `getCounterfactual` function to get the address you want. Every Safe Multisig address has been deployed with some nonce/salt . Enter the same salt and you might be able to get the same on base